# Why does visual studio put CommandText in resx resource file vs designer code behind file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, resx, visual-studio-designer

Sometimes my queries that are stored in `OdbcCommand.CommandText` are saved to the designer.cx code behind, and sometimes in the .resx resource file.  What causes it to go to the code behind vs the resource file?

And is there a way to force visual studio to save my queries in the resource file (or vice versa) so I'm not having to look in both places.

Comment: Within the same project?  Within the same file?

Comment: Yes.  The resource file is tied to the designer file in the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after some googling I found the answer posted [here](http://www.44342.com/dotnet-framework-f71-t11668-p1.htm):

> I have examined it a little further. It appears that the commandtext is 
>   saved in the resource when it's length is more the 200 characters. This not 
>   only applies to the commandtext property, but to all string properties, e.g. 
>   the Label.Text. It's saved to the resouce even if the localizable property of 
>   the form, usercontrol or component is false. When you decrease the length of 
>   the string, the property is removed from the resource file and placed in the 
>   Designer.cs file.
>   So it seems you have no control over the fact if a lengthy string is saved 
>   in the resource or not. In the case of the commandtext that's very 
>   dangerouse, because a translator of the resource could change the commandtext 
>   to a wrong statement.

Apparently there's not way to change this behavior.  I did confirm there is a 200 character limit excluding white space.